# SqlDataAdapter.RowUpdating()- How to Cancel that Row Update, while the Fiels is Null?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'am using sqlserver2008.

I have a select query

```
Con.Open();
String MyQuery="Select * from MyTable where MyField1 is not null";
MySQLDataAdapter=New SqlDataAdapter(MyQuery,Con);
MySQLDataAdapter.Fill(MyTable);
Con.Close();

For (int I1=0;I1<=50;I1++)
{
 DataRow DRw = MyTable.NewRow();
 MyTable.Rows.Add(DRw); //Null Columns are added
}
blah...blah...blah..

//For Save
MyWMSDatas.VehDAp.Update(MyTable);
```

Now what I need that, I want ro raise the `SqlDataAdapter.RowUpdating()`
and would like to update while myField1 is not null and for Null that row should not be update...

Any Ideas ....

Thanks For The Helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a handler to the `RowUpdating` event of your adapter:

```
MyWMSDatas.VehDAp.RowUpdating += VehDAp_RowUpdating
```

In the handler, check `myField1` and set the `Status` Property of the argument `e` (*of type [RowUpdatingEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlrowupdatingeventargs.aspx)*) to [UpdateStatus.SkipCurrentRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.updatestatus.aspx) (or any other value you see more suitable like `ErrorsOccurred`...):

```
private static void OnRowUpdating(object sender, SqlRowUpdatingEventArgs e) 
{
    if(e.Row....myField1...)
        e.Status =  UpdateStatus.SkipCurrentRow
    ....
}
```